# keras/theano-how to return a constant in lambda

Tags: python, lambda, keras, theano

I'm trying to use lambda layer in keras to return a Euclidean distance of two vectors. The code is:

```
def distance(x):
    a=x[0]
    b=x[1]
    dist=np.linalg.norm(a-b)
    return dist
dist=Lambda(distance,output_shape=(1,1)name='dist')([x,y])
```

The input of this layer are two vectors of (100,1,8192). The 100 is the batch.The output is a constant in theory. And I want to use dist as output of this model like:

```
model = Model(inputs=[probe_input_car,probe_input_sign,gallary_input_car,gallary_input_sign], outputs=dist, name='fcn')`
```

When I run this model, there will be a error:

```
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[2] = 1, input[1].shape[2] = 8192)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Composite{EQ(i0, RoundHalfToEven(i1))}}(/dist_target, Elemwise{Composite{sqrt(sqr(i0))}}.0)
Toposort index: 92
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D)]
Inputs shapes: [(100, 1, 1), (100, 1, 8192)]
Inputs strides: [(4, 4, 4), (32768, 32768, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Sum{acc_dtype=int64}(Elemwise{Composite{EQ(i0, RoundHalfToEven(i1))}}.0)]]
```

I think this is caused by the output_shape of lambda layer. How should I set the output_shape of the layer. Because I use theano as the backend, it can't calculate the output_shape itself.
And if it is not caused by output_shape. Where is the error?

Comment: Can you post the line where you "run" this model?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're simply getting the wrong parts of the vector.

The message says it's trying to compute something with two tensors shaped as:

- (100,1,1)
- (100,1,8192)

Based on your input list, where you have `[car,signal,car2,signal2]`. I believe you probably want some operation betwen either `car x car` or `signal x signal`.

So, your lambda layer should probably start as either:

```
a = x[0]
b = x[2]
```

or:

```
a = x[1]
b = x[3]
```

**Hint:** if you're able to find an equivalent function in [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/) to calculate what you want, it's probably better. I wonder how you haven't got a "disconnected" error message for using a numpy function.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you used `np.linalg.norm()` on a Theano tensor. It doesn't throw an error, but the output is definitely not what you expect.

To avoid this error, use Keras backend functions instead. For example,

```
dist = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(a - b), axis=-1, keepdims=True))
```

**What happened inside np.linalg.norm(x):**

1. `x = np.asarray(x)` wraps `a - b` into a length-1 array (of dtype `object`) whose only element is a Theano tensor of shape (100, 1, 8192).
2. `sqnorm = np.dot(x, x)`: recall the definition of dot product. When you dot a length-1 array with itself, you're actually computing `(a - b) * (a - b)`, or an element-wise square of `a - b`. That's why there's `sqr(i0)` in the second line of your error.
3. `np.sqrt(sqnorm)` is returned. So you can see `sqrt(sqr(i0))` appear in your error.
4. Therefore, the output of `np.linalg.norm(a - b)` is a tensor of shape (100, 1, 8192), not (100, 1, 1).

Also, if you look closer into [the code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L20-L21), `Elemwise{Composite{EQ(i0, RoundHalfToEven(i1))}}` is just accuracy.

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

So the error message is trying to tell you that there's a mismatch between the shapes of `y_true` and `y_pred`. While `y_true` is of shape (100, 1, 1), `y_pred` has a shape (100, 1, 8192) because `np.linalg.norm()` gives wrong results for Theano tensors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It starts work after using your method.